# Método para ordenar una lista de menores por genero en java

Tags: java, lista

quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar para crear un método que me permita ordenar o transformar (alternadamente) por genero una lista de menores de edad en java. Adjunto el código de como lo estoy haciendo. Gracias

```
public void transformar(Lista<PoblacionMenores> lista1){
    PoblacionMenores menor1;
    PoblacionMenores menor2;
    menor1 = listaMenores.get(listaMenores.size()-1);

    if(menor1.getGenero()=='M'){
        for (int i = 0; i < listaMenores.size(); i++) {
            menor1 = (PoblacionMenores)listaMenores.get(i);
            if(menor1.getGenero() == 'F' && (i > 0 && i < listaMenores.size()-1)){
                menor2 = listaMenores.get(i +1);
                if(menor2.getGenero() == 'M'){
                listaMenores.set(i , menor2);
                listaMenores.set(i + 1, menor1);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < listaMenores.size(); i++){
            menor1 = (PoblacionMenores) listaMenores.get(i);
            if(menor1.getGenero() == 'M' && (i > 0 && i < listaMenores.size()-1)){
                menor2 = listaMenores.get(i + 1);
                if(menor2.getGenero() == 'F'){
                    listaMenores.set(i, menor2);
                    listaMenores.set(i + 1, menor1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi recomendación sería ordenar la lista de objetos de acuerdo a la propiedad que requieres y luego mezclarlos.

Para la solución se están usando ya funciones lambda por lo cual deberías trabajar con Java 8 o superior, supongo que no hay problema con ello.

**Algoritmo:**

- Ordenar el arrayList:

Mediante el método [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) que recibe una lista y un [comparador](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) estamos ordenando de acuerdo al valor numérico de gender con el método [`comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) de esta manera:

`list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(CustomObject::getGender));`

- Mezclar el arrayList:

Para ello se divide en dos sub arreglos, si hay más mujeres que hombres se mezclan los hombres entre las mujeres, de caso contrario las mujeres se mezclan con los hombres.

Lo anterior se puede apreciar en la línea `women.add(i, men.remove(men.size() - 1));` y su equivalente

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<>(5);

        list.add(new CustomObject(9, 'M', "Paco"));
        list.add(new CustomObject(10, 'M', "Beto"));
        list.add(new CustomObject(10, 'M', "Carlos"));
        list.add(new CustomObject(11, 'F', "Diana"));
        list.add(new CustomObject(10, 'F', "Clara"));
        list.add(new CustomObject(9, 'F', "Carlota"));

        // Sorting the arraylist by gender
        list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(CustomObject::getGender));
        // Mixing the arraylist
        list = mixList(list);

        // print the Arraylist
        for (CustomObject co : list )
            System.out.printf("\n%s\t%d\t%c", co.name, co.age, co.gender);

    }

    /**
     * This function mix the elements so they're paired
     * @param list Sorted by gender ArrayList<CustomObject>
     * @return Mixed one to one ArrayList
     */
    private static ArrayList<CustomObject> mixList(ArrayList<CustomObject> list) {
        // finding the index of the first object with gender == 'M'
        int idx = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .filter(i -> list.get(i).gender == 'M')
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(-1);

        // If the list are full of men or full of women just returns the list
        if (idx < 1)
            return list;

        ArrayList<CustomObject> women = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(0, idx));
        ArrayList<CustomObject> men = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(idx, list.size()));

        int i = 1;
        // if there are more women than men
        if (idx > list.size() / 2) {
            while (!men.isEmpty()) {
                women.add(i, men.remove(men.size() - 1));
                i += 2;
            }
            return women;
        } else {
            while (!women.isEmpty()) {
                men.add(i, women.remove(women.size() - 1));
                i += 2;
            }
            return men;
        }
    }

    private static class CustomObject {

        final int age;
        final char gender;
        final String name;

        private CustomObject(int age, char gender, String name) {
            this.age = age;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.name = name;
        }

        protected char getGender() {
            return gender;
        }
    }

}
```

Los resultados de la ejecución del anterior programa serían:

```
Paco    9   M
Carlota 9   F
Beto    10  M
Clara   10  F
Carlos  10  M
Diana   11  F
```

Hay otra solución que te podría ser útil; después de ordenar tu arreglo, podrías intentarlo con el método [`swap` de Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List,%20int,%20int)).

Si es estrictamente necesario que si el primero es de género "H" se inicie con "H" y de la misma manera con "M", basta con modificar un poco el código.

Comment: **Nota: ** Fíjate que se tiene la línea `men.remove(men.size() - 1)`, esto se hace así dada la naturaleza de de los `ArrayList` como arreglos dinámicos para mejorar el rendimiento del programa, esto porque de ponerlo como `men.remove(0)` en teoría se estarían moviendo los elementos hacia la izquierda, por lo cual en un data set muy grande se vería un poco perjudicado el rendimiento. Sin embargo, si necesitas que estén en orden se solucionaría:

Comment: 1.- con el remove(0); 2.- invirtiendo el orden de la lista, donde te sugeriría usar [`Collections.reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo tu pregunta, veo que recibes un parámetro genérico que nunca usas (lista1) para esta solución supondré que esa lista1 es la ordenada de menores de edad, lo idea sería crear un objeto donde guardes la lista ordenada y un auxiliar que recorra la desordenada, así:

```
Lista<PoblacionMenores> listaOrdenada = new Lista<PoblacionMenores>();
Lista<PoblacionMenores>[] aux;
int contador = 0;
aux = lista1.getListaMenores();
  for(int i = 0; i< lista1.getSize();i++){
    if((aux[i].getGenero() == 'M') && (i%2 == 0)){
    listaOrdenada.set(i, aux[i]);
  }else if((aux[i].getGenero == 'M') && (i%2 != 0)){
    listaOrdenada.set(i+1,aux[i]);
    contador++;
   }else if ((aux[i].getGenero() == 'F') && (contador == 0) && (i%2 != 0)){
     listaOrdenada.set(i, aux[i]);
   }else if((aux[i].getGenero() == 'F') && (contador != 0)){
     listaOrdenada.set(i-contador, aux[i]);
     contador--;
   }
```

El código anterior busca posicionar a 'M' en las posiciones pares y 'F' en las impares, el método "debería" ser funcional (no comprobé si tiene errores) para listas con igual número de 'F' y 'M', de lo contrarío se deberían eliminar espacios vacíos en la lista.

Si es necesario darle un tamaño a listaOrdenada antes de usarla si hay diferente cantidad de 'F' y de 'M' debería ser la cantidad de 'M' + (la diferencia entre la cantidad 'F' - 'M'), lo que implicaría el uso de un bucle para contar las cantidades primero; en caso de ser cantidades iguales el tamaño el es número de elementos de lista1.

Comment: lista1.getListaMenores() en caso de no tener este método considere crearlo, retornaría un array completo de menores de edad